# javascript function is not a function but it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm trying to make a HTML button trigger a function called `switch_user`, but every time I try clicking it, the console says `switch_user` is not a function.

This is the button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-login" onclick="switch_user()" id="switch_user" value="{%trans%}Switch{%endtrans%}">
```

At the bottom of the page I have a script tag, with this function in it:

```
function switch_user(){
  $("#switch-success, #switch-error").addClass("hide");

  $.getJSON("/api/business/admin/swaproles?module="+$("#module").val()+"&user_from="+$("#user_from").val()+"&user_to="+$("#user_to").val(), function(data){
      if(data) {
          if(data["error"]){
              $("#switch-error").html( "{%trans%}There was an error{%endtrans%}: " + data["error"]);
              $("#switch-error").removeClass("hide");
          }
          else {
              $("#switch-success").html("{%trans%}User was switched successfully{%endtrans%}");
              $("#switch-success").removeClass("hide");
          }
          if(data["success"] == "ok") {
              $("#elements").html("");
          }

      } else {
          $("#switch-error").html("Critical failure - Please contact support");
          $("#switch-error").removeClass("hide");
      }
  });

}
```

[image]

When I try to run the function manually from the console, it can find it just fine, but the buttons onclick refuses to recognize it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming you've put the `switch_user()` function definition inside a document.ready handler, and is therefore not in scope of the `on*` event attribute. Either move the function definition to the `window` scope, or better still get rid of the outdated `on*` event handler completely and attach your events using unobtrusive JS

Comment: Have you tried moving the `script` tag above the `input`?  If you're doing it inline like this, I think it needs to already be available.  Alternatively, register the event properly after the function is declared (not using an attribute) and this should work ok as well.

Comment: i think just change the id from switch_user to something else. don't keep the function name and id of element same

Comment: The position of the script tag doesn't matter for inline click events.

Comment: @prabhjot it worked by changing the id, but can you tell me exactly why this was a problem?

Comment: It's because the `id` attributes are set as properties of the `window` object by default. You have also defined a function with the same name, at the same scope, hence there's a conflict. This is yet another reason why using `on*` attributes and global functions is really not good practice.

Comment: I thought it was the ID as well ... but using the same id and function works in IE, Edge, FF and Chrum

Comment: If the two answers about the id and function name are correct ... why does https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/w9ejeypr/2/ work? in IE11, Edge, Fx and Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `id` of the element and the function name are the same. As they both exist under the `window` scope, there is a conflict. To fix the immediate problem either change the name of the function or the `id` of the element.

Better still, remove the outdated `on*` event attribute completely and use unobtrusive JS code to attach the event handler. As you're using jQuery already, here's how to do that:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-login" id="switch_user" value="{%trans%}Switch{%endtrans%}">
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#switch_user').on('click', function() {
    var $switchSuccess = $('#switch-success').addClass('hide');
    var $switchError = $('#switch-error').addClass('hide');

    $.getJSON("/api/business/admin/swaproles?module=" + $("#module").val() + "&user_from=" + $("#user_from").val() + "&user_to=" + $("#user_to").val(), function(data) {
      if (data) {
        if (data["error"]) {
          $switchError.html("{%trans%}There was an error{%endtrans%}: " + data["error"]).removeClass("hide");
        } else {
          $switchSuccess.html("{%trans%}User was switched successfully{%endtrans%}").removeClass("hide");
        }

        if (data["success"] == "ok") {
          $("#elements").html("");
        }
      } else {
        $switchError.html("Critical failure - Please contact support").removeClass("hide");
      }
    });

  })
});
```

Comment: what does {%trans%} do?

Comment: I'm assuming that's part of a templating library the OP is using, or possibly some server side code that's injected in.

Comment: Ho right, mybad, thought that was only in your answer didn't see it in op's code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the id . don't keep the id of element and function name same.

The JavaScript DOM bindings allow indexing by HTML id. Functions and properties share the same namespace in JavaScript. So, when an id in your HTML has the same name as one of your functions or properties, you can get logic errors that are hard to track down. While this is more of a CSS best practice issue, it’s important to remember when you can’t solve your javascript issue.